# Creating example values in SQLite database using strings from strings.xml

Tags: android, android-xml

I got this class, which creates database at the 1st run of the app. I wanted to fill one table with some example values from strings.xml. Basically I'd do this like:

```
private static final String CATEGORIES_FILL = "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + getString(R.string.fuel) + "); " +
                                              "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + getString(R.string.food) + "); " +
                                              "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + getString(R.string.treatment) + "); " +
                                              "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + getString(R.string.salary) + "); ";
```

The problem is, the class is not an activity, and string must be static so I can use

```
db.execSQL(CATEGORIES_FILL);
```

Please correct my approach so I could use strings.xml to do that.

I assume I could do that in my activity class surrounding it with try block, but I don't like the idea of executing this every time I open the activity.

**Fragment of database class**

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


        final String CATEGORIES_FILL = "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + context.getString(R.string.fuel) + "); " +
        "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + context.getString(R.string.food) + "); " +
        "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + context.getString(R.string.treatment) + "); " +
        "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + context.getString(R.string.salary) + "); "; 
    }

    /* Tworzenie tabel
     * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(CATEGORIES_FILL); //need the way to access this final here
        db.execSQL(EXPENSES_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(INCOMES_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(BUGS_CREATE);            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something vaguely like this.

Add to res/values/*<yourchoiceoffilename>*.xml & add your string references to a string-array.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="categories">
        <item>@string/fuel</item>
        <item>@string/food</item>
        <item>@string/treatment</item>
        <item>@string/salary</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Create a SQLiteStatement on your database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO categories (yourcolumnnamehere) VALUES (?)");

//process each string
for (String category : getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories)) 
{
    insert.bindValue(1, category);
    long id = insert.executeInsert(); // In case you care about the row id.
}
```

**Edit**: And, consider doing something *like* following to your class (I've probably left a bug or two in there, but you should get the gist of it):

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ...
    // Replace 'yourcolumnnamehere' with whatever your column is actually named.
    private static final String INSERT_CATEGORY = "INSERT INTO categories (yourcolumnamehere) VALUES (?)"
    ...
    ...

    private final String[] mCategories;
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mCategories = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        // Here you create the SQLiteStatement that will be used
        // to add categories. The values are stored in mCategories.
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(INSERT_CATEGORY);
        for (String category : mCategories) {
            statement.bindValue(1, category);
            statement.executeInsert();
        }
        statement.close();

        db.execSQL(EXPENSES_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(INCOMES_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(BUGS_CREATE);            
    }
```

Comment: but I can't use getResources if class doesnt extend Activity right? And what's the input in the (?) place

Comment: Any Context will be able to get you Resources. ? is a placeholder used when binding values to a pre-compiled SQLite statement. Where are you doing this since you have no access to a Context.

Comment: doing it in the databaseadapter class where database, tables and stuff are created

Comment: So, for any sane implementation, a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper I take it? The SQLiteOpenHelper constructor takes a Context, save a reference to that parameter of your own (since it doesn't define a helpful getContext) and use that.

Comment: edited my question, look at that fragment of code, kindly please :)

Comment: Yup, you got a Context available. Call context.getResources() .getStringArray(R.array.categories) to retrieve an array of strings stored in your resources. While you "can" make complete SQL Strings that hold your values its better to use a SQLiteStatement since bound column values will be escaped properly and not break your SQL.

Comment: but I can't access the context in onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) which is the problem

Comment: Store it as a field in your DatabaseHelper. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<string-array name="categories">
        <item>aaaaaa</item>
        <item>bbbbbbbb</item>
        <item>cccccccc</item>
        <item>ddddd</item>
</string-array>
```

Instead of adding String , add string array to string.xml
Then in Java retrieve it using :

```
String[] categoriesAndDescriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
    for(String cad : categoriesAndDescriptions) {
        String categoryAndDesc = cad;
        list.add(categoryAndDesc);
    }
```

list is ArrayList, after you get one value store it in Arraylist.

Now Populate this ArayList to Insert Query, you can get first value using `list.get(0)`

Comment: getResources is also Context class based. i can't use id on non-activity class

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private Resources mResources;

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

   mResources = context.getResources();

   final String CATEGORIES_FILL = "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + mResources.getString(R.string.fuel) + "); " +
                "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + mResources.getString(R.string.food) + "); " +
                "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + mResources.getString(R.string.treatment) + "); " +
                "INSERT INTO categories VALUES ('', " + mResources.getString(R.string.salary) + "); "; 
            }
```